# What are some good specification/requirements document items for a small iPhone app project?

Tags: iphone, specifications, requirements

I'm whipping up a short specifications/requirements document for a small prototype iPhone app project.  Describing the basic functionality and behavior is not an issue for me.  But, since my mobile application and iPhone development knowledge is very weak, I'm not really sure what else should be in such a document regarding best practices and such.

***Example:*** In my programming world (server side Java), when spec'ing a project for outsourcing, I state that the project must pass static bug analysis by FindBugs.

***Example:*** I understand that there are API calls Apple does not want app developers invoking.  These can be cause for having an app rejected from the app store.  But I'm not sure how to say that we want Apple's guidelines respected.  (I don't even know how to test for that.)

What should I include in a two-page requirements and specification document that is specific to iPhone app development?

Comment: You can't really test for undocumented API usage, but you can certainly ask in your spec doc for absolutely no APIs that are not in the public documentation. That covers what Apple cares about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are some points you can mention
 1. The application should be developed based on Apple's user interface guidelines
 2. There should not be any private API call inside the project which makes the application rejected from apple
 3. There should not be any memory leak or excess memory allocation issue during the application running state
 4. The application should be supported in all iOS after [your option]. (It mainly depends on the features used in the application)
 5. The application should be supported in iOS 4
 6. The application should work properly on iPhone 4

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A private API wont be mentioned in any header file or in the documentation so one way to test for that would be to manually go through the source files and search for the functions used in the headers and documentation to see that they are there. It's really not feasable if the project grows but for a small app it could work :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the things already mentioned here, I'd add a few more:

- The app should work *fast*, no action should give the user the feeling, the device is doing something
- Everything that takes a while should be run in background and even better, be cancelable
- Make sure you use animation only where it makes sense but not too seldom. A smooth feeling is most important for users.
- These things also imply that you try to minimize application startup time.

There are often tricks to work around performance issues. The feeling a users gets from your application is not how fast it is, but how fast if *feels*. In my opinion this is the single most critical requirement, besides obvious ones like no crashes etc..

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with using a private API?

Moreover, I would add that it will be tested on iPhone 3G, 3GS, iPod, 4, all with iOS4 and 3.

Comment: Apple does not particularly like the practice: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2008/12/private-iphone-api-crackdown-in-progress.ars  That could mean more development cost *just to keep the status quo*, my App in the App Store